# Google Analytics is tracking users on a non-existant landing page

Tags: google-analytics

I have this strange issue but not sure how to solve. I will try my best to explain it in detail.

I made a new landing page at `http://example.com` to capture early interest from online users. I then setup a GA attached to this domain name to track traffic. After a few days, I decided to redirect users to that domain name to `http://example.com.au` (using PHP 301 header redirect).

Now that I made a few attempts to draw traffic to the new domain name (`.com.au`), I see very little traffic coming in though I know that the ads does attract a few thousand viewers. When I look into GA User Behavior tabs, there was quite a few people landing onto a strange directory that I have no idea where it is.

[image]

The strange directory is `/landing-ohmyaww/` (ohmyaww is the site name) and that directory does not exist on the server. Also note that:

- `index.php` is on `http://example.com.au`
- `home.php` is on `http://example.com`

Does anybody know what is potentially a problem here?

Comment: This problem is on your server settings. It depends on server type - NGINX, Apache, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude know bots from showing in your GA by checking the bot filtering box at the basic settings tab.